# Accessing a Macbook Air using Ubunu

Tags: networking, macbook, hfs+

So my ancient Macbook air (2013) is non-functional after a failed OS update.

I'd like to use a live distro to backup files from the harddrive (and in an ideal world perhaps even repair the installation). Unfortunately, there's no Ethernet port in these machines, and Ubuntu Live doesn't seem to have HFS+ support out of the box.

I can't simply install hfsprogs from the net, as Ubuntu doesn't seem to support the WIFI adapter in the Macbook air.

I'm wondering is there a version of Ubuntu, or another live distro that has native HFS+ support built in? Or even one that supports the macbook air WIFI adapter?

Comment: If you have access to another system, you can always build your own ISO with the applications you need.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Hey thanks for the info. I do indeed have access to another system. But it's a windows system, rather than a Unix one. Those instructions are tailored to building a live CD from within Ubuntu. Is this possible to do from Windows or Mac OS?

Comment: I guess you could install Virtualbox into Windows then install Ubuntu as a guest into it then build one in there.